# custom font picker in shopify not working as expected

Tags: fonts, shopify

Hello i have this settings in settings_schema.json:

```
"name": "Typography",
    "settings": [
      {
        "type": "font_picker",
        "id": "font_heading",
        "default": "helvetica_n4",
        "label": "Headings"
      },
      {
        "type": "font_picker",
        "id": "font_body",
        "default": "helvetica_n4",
        "label": "Body text"
      },
      {
        "type": "header", 
        "content": "Main Heading Text" 
      },
      {
        "type": "font_picker",
        "id": "Main_heading_font_new",
        "label": "Main heading Font",
        "default": "work_sans_n6"
      }
    ]
```

And i have this style in my navbar.liquied

```
<style lang="scss">  

  {% assign header_font = settings.Main_heading_font_new %}
  {{ header_font | font_face }}

  $font-stack-header: {{ header_font.family }}, {{ header_font.fallback_families }};

  #shopname{    
    font-family: $font-stack-header;
  }
  </style>
```

and i have this html code in navbar.liquied

```
<div  id="shopname" ><a  href="/" >DAVIT'S JEWELS</a></div>
```

But it is not applaying the font to the "shopname" element, it is not selecting even the "shopname" elelment , i have tryied to make inline styling but that is not working also like this:

```
<div  id="shopname" style="font-family:beefcakes_i4 ;" ><a  href="/" >DAVIT'S JEWELS</a></div>
```

Can you help me please. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have styled like this:

```
<style lang="scss">
 {% assign header_font = settings.Main_heading_font_new %}
  {{ header_font | font_face }}    
  .shopname{    
    font-family: {{ header_font.family }},{{ header_font.fallback_families }};        
  }
</style>
```

And html part is:

```
<div  class="shopname" ><a  href="/" >DAVIT'S JEWELS</a></div>
```

And it works.